# Проблемы с элементом FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеются проблемы с элементом `FlowLayoutPanel` в программе.
У меня существует `UserControlPanel` - так вот этот элемент я в отдельном потоке бесконечно, добавляю в эту `FlowLayoutPanel`.

```
UserControlPanel panel = new UserControlPanel(a, spisok);
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(panel, 0);
```

Вставляю каждый новый `UserControlPanel` в начало `FlowLayoutPanel`, а остальные `UserControlPanel` сдвигаются вправо и если по горизонтали всё заполнено, переставляются на новую строку.
А в случае заполнения вертикали `FlowLayoutPanel`, у неё появляется скролл.

Т.е. всё работает как надо.

**Но проблема вот в чём:**

Так вот представим, что скролл находится на самом верху или по середине.
И если приложение находится не в актином окне, и я к нему обращусь, кликнув в любую область `FlowLayoutPanel`, скролл улетает вниз и мне каждый раз приходится крутить его вверх, что бы смотреть что там добавляется в начале.

Как такое лечится ?

**UPDATE: Добавил пример проекта**
https://yadi.sk/d/SOkWH3xL3Qczeh

Каждые 3 секунды добавляется `UserConrol` в `FLP`, когда заполняется `FLP` по вертикали, появляется скролл и если скрыть любой `Conrol` по спец. кнопке , скролл улетает вниз, а не остаётся на месте и тоже самое происходит, когда кликаю по форме если она неактивна.

Comment: Я не совсем уверен, что правильно всё понял. Можно после `SetChildIndex` добавить `panel.Select();` Это активирует контрол, помещая фокус на него. Так что свежедобавленная панель сразу же будет видна. Однако, это будет мешать смотреть панели внизу...

Comment: После того как на flp добавили новый контрол, вызовите у добавленного контрола метод Focus(). Скрол подстроится таким образом, чтобы добавленный элемент был в видимой части flp. Вам это нужно? Просто из вопроса понятна проблема, но не понятно ожидаемое правильное поведение.

Comment: @rdorn чуть забыл про этот вопрос, но проблема актуальна. Нужно именно то, что вы говорите. Чтобы в фокусе был всегда новый UserControlPanel, а при скрытии этого нового UserControlPanel (this.Parent?.Controls.Remove(this);), фокус перемещался бы на предыдущий.

Comment: Написал ответом. Там все просто. Дополнения из комментария перенесите в текст вопроса. И еще, вам нужна прямо явная передача фокуса при удалении или просто сохранение поведения панели при удалении элемента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для удобства добавления новых элементов на `FlowLayoutPanel`, подписываемся на событие `Control.ControlAdded` таким обработчиком:

```
flowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    var flp = (FlowLayoutPanel)sender;
    flp.Controls.SetChildIndex(e.Control, 0);
    flp.ScrollControlIntoView(e.Control);
}
```

В отличие от методов `Control.Select()` и `Control.Focus()`, которые переключают фокус на выбранный контрол и мешают работать с другими контролами на той же форме, метод `ScrollableControl.ScrollControlIntoView(Control)` не перехватывает фокус, а только сдвигает скрол так, чтобы переданный в параметре дочерний элемент оказался в видимой области. Поэтому вы можете, например, спокойно печатать в `TextBox` во время добавления новых элементов.

Данный обработчик будет возвращать скрол в самое верхнее положение, чтобы обеспечить видимость добавленного элемента. Между добавлениями можете крутить его как хотите, хотя если элементы добавляются часто, то из этого мало что получится, но подергать для проверки можно.

Comment: Спасибо большое что не прошли мимо, вроде работает так, как хотелось.

Comment: @Vipz рад что помогло

Comment: появилась проблема с которой боролся ранее, когда форма неактивна и я обращаюсь к ней (кликаю по ней) скролл улетает вниз.

Comment: @Vipz значит в вашем коде есть еще что-то, что заставляет ее себя так вести или не совсем корректно адаптировали пример под свои нужды. Тут уже без отладчика ни чего не скажешь. Попробуйте пройтись по шагам, помотрите кто добавляет контролы. что делают сами контролы и т.д.

Comment: @Vipz попробуйте в отдельном проекте по таймеру добавлять, ну например, кнопки на FLP описанным способом и попробуйте воспроизвести проблему, если получится, допишите в вопрос как воспроизвести, если не получится - ищите ошибку в коде основного проекта

Comment: Обновил вопрос и добавил ссылку Яндекс.Диск на пример проекта - если будет что то неудобно, дайте пожалуйста знать.

Comment: @Vipz проект посмотрел, но не нашел там реализации предложенного решения. На события FLP ни кто не подписан, так что поведение абсолютно логичное.

Comment: Прошу прощения, заменил ссылку - там есть Ваша реализация.

Comment: @Vipz ну раз у вас элемент сам себя удаляет, то пусть позаботится и о возврате фокуса Parent-у перед удалением. В выходные попробую найти ответ на вопрос почему, скорее всего что-то унаследованное, как обычно. Но простая передача фокуса родителю дает нужный эффект. Странно то, что скрол вываливается в самый конец, хотя должен по идее оставаться там где был

Comment: Фуххх, ещё раз спасибо! Возврат фокуса паренту решил 90% проблем.

Comment: Удивляюсь, что ваши хорошие ответы собирают так мало голосов.

Comment: @4per это нормально. Я не охочусь за голосами, иначе бы отвечал только в модных метках на модных языках =) Просто делюсь теми знаниями, которые есть, попутно получая новые. Нет лучше способа что-то понять лучше, чем объяснить это другому.